# how to make background full-size

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css, how do I make the background full-size?  I'm assuming it would be in the css?

```
body {
  background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Hi, please remember to always Google first. I'm sure `CSS how to make background full-size` will turn up plenty of useful results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
  background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /*-- Used for Chrome and Safari browsers --*/
  -moz-background-size: cover; /*-- Used for Firefox browser --*/
  -o-background-size: cover; /*-- Used for Opera browser --*/
  background-size: cover; /*-- Used for IE browser --*/
}
```

Comment: If you're using the values `contain` or `cover`, none of the vendor prefixes are necessary because support for those values only appeared after the vendor prefix was dropped. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)